# Package by the same name a conflicting signature is already installed

Tags: android, android-studio, target-sdk

At Offset, scenario is different than the question available on stack for the same question. I am posting this question after lot of research.

Getting an error message

> Package by the same name a conflicting signature is already installed

### Scenario 1

Steps to generate signed apk that I followed..

Build--> Generate Signed apk--->popup (filled all fields with same details in both scenarios)--->Click next ---> popup (Chosen released, signature version both ticked in both cases) and finish.

1. App installed from Playstore on phone (Version 1)
2. Create an app update (signed) with same key (Just increased targetsdk version to 26 only as an update) (Version 1.1)
3. Copy apk to phone & try to update but get above error.

### Scenario 2

1. App installed by creating signed apk with same key and installed on app (Version 1 as in playstore)
2. Create an app update (signed) with same key (Just increased targetsdk version to 26 only as an update) (Version 1.1)
3. Copy apk to phone & try to update but no error.

Please help me with possible area of errors.

Comment: @CommonsWare any help?

Comment: Please do not put arbitrary tags on questions. This question has nothing to do with one of my CWAC libraries; it did not need the `commonsware-cwac` tag. With respect to your problem, apparently there is something different about how you are doing Step #2 compared with how you created the APK that is presently on the Play Store. You might wish to edit your question and provide more details of how you are performing those steps.

Comment: @CommonsWare updated details.

Comment: Solution is: https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/app-not-installedthe-package-conflicts-with-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-android/

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you use same : there is new v2 sing scheme which could be incompatible with v1(https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2) maybe it's default for 26 api

Another path: maybe you use your **upload key** instead of real one which you uploaded to your developer console and apk released in playstore is in fact signed by it.

Comment: same key has been used & signatures v1 & v2 has been used in both cases.

Comment: @AmanSrii as i see you found solution. Great to hear. Please share short description here as answer and accept it as correct so other users will be able to use it.

As i see RCA was that google play store "sign" apk with own key, i'm i correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the application using ADB command:

```
adb install -l -r name-of-file.apk
```

Source: https://android-fix.com/android-errors/75-app-not-installed-error.html